# NGXS storage plugin and lazily loaded state

Tags: angular, ngxs

At my company I have a pretty complicated application structure. We are using the NX Workspace to develop 3 applications with shared modules across all of them.

Our app structure looks something like this: apps -->app1 -->app2 -->app3

libs -->auth module with components and ngxs state -->other shared modules with components and ngxs state

All of our libs are lazily loaded into each app that needs it.

So the issue I am having is with the ngxs storage plugin. It seems that it has to be imported into each app module and if you don't specify the keys then it dumps every state into local or session storage (we are using session storage). This would be perfectly fine with me if it wasn't for the router state getting added as well.

It seems that when the router state is in session storage, when you try to navigate to another page by manually typing in the link in the url bar, it redirects you back to the previous page that was navigated to by the router.

I have searched around and everyone seems to just suggest you don't store the router in session storage. If there is another workaround for this PLEASE let me know!

If there isn't a workaround for the router issue, then that brings me to my next problem/question. I want to be able to add states to storage individually but I also want to keep that code with the module that the state belongs to rather than having to add it in each app's AppModule. We will have a very large application and to have to map each state from all of our libs in each of our apps will be exhausting.

There isn't a forFeature option for the storage plugin but has this been considered for complex apps like mine?

I can raise an issue in github about it but wanted to reach out to the community here to be sure there isn't already a solution out there that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that when the router state is in session storage, when you try to navigate to another page by manually typing in the link in the url bar, it redirects you back to the previous page that was navigated to by the router.

I encounter the same problem with `@ngxs/router-plugin@3.2.0`.

> I have searched around and everyone seems to just suggest you don't store the router in session storage. If there is another workaround for this PLEASE let me know!

I can manually navigate to different routes if the router is not stored in the session object. However, now I have to specify each state individually in the `NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({key: ['auth', 'users', '...']})`.

I found another solution without using the router-plugin. This requires you to setup your own router state ([example](https://github.com/codediodeio/ngrx-vs-ngxs/blob/master/ngxs/src/app/shared/router.state.ts) by angularfirebase):

```
@Action(Navigate)
  async changeRoute(context: StateContext<string>, action: Navigate) {
    const path = action.payload;
    await this.router.navigate([path]);
    context.setState( path );
  }
```

Now I can manually navigate to any page by typing the link in the url bar and all states are stored in the session storage including the route path.

Hope this works for you as well.